# Can't access global array outside of an if statement?

Tags: php, arrays, scope, global

I am having some issues with setting a global array in php. The data I get from $_POST is straight from my database. I sent it through an external page to JSON decode/etc. (that part works, so I didnt paste the code). I only want to do this if data is set, then I want to take that array and do other things with it throughout the rest of my code. The problem I am having is the array outside of the if statement is null. I can't seem to figure out why? If I were to echo a var_dump inside the if statement, the values are inside the GLOBALS['Array']

```
 function is_assoc($array) {
   foreach (array_keys($array) as $k => $v) {
     if ($k !== $v)
      return true;
     }
     return false;
   }

$GLOBALS['Array'] = array(); 

if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
   $Data = $_POST['data'];

   $decode = new JSONdecoder($Data);
   $decode->decodeNew($Data);
   $Data = $decode->decodedArray;

   $decryptor = new DataDecryptor(base64_decode($_POST['key']), $_POST['tracking'], $hostName);
   $decodedData =  $decryptor->decrypt_arr($Data);

   foreach($decodedData as $key => $val){
      if(is_assoc($val)){
         foreach($val as $key2 => $val2){
            $theArray[$key2] = $val2;
         }      
      }else{
         $theArray[$key] = $val;
      }
    }

 $GLOBALS['Array'] = $theArray;
}
echo var_Dump($Array);
```

Comment: $Array is not set in this piece of code ..

Comment: The last line should be `echo var_dump($GLOBALS['Array']);`

Comment: Sry, Are you referring to the last statement echo var_Dump($Array);? I thought when you referenced the global outside of the function you just called it the name of the variable.

Comment: It should be `var_dump($GLOBALS['Array']);` instead of what you have right now.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But to be fair, the website I referenced was misleading... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Comment: `echo $Array` should have worked. The documentation is right. For example : `$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'bar'; echo $foo;` will output `bar`. The issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I agree @alfallouji because whenever I try to use the $GLOBALS['Array'] inside of another function it is null again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is somewhere else. $GLOBALS is a superglobal variable accessible from any scope.

When you define a new entry in $GLOBALS, it automatically creates a variable holding the same name, but that variable is only visible in that particular scope. If you are in another scope and you want to initialize that as a variable, you need to use the `global` keyword : `global $var;` (look at the code below for an example - inside the `test()` function).

Are you sure 100% that you are always doing the same tests (Are you 100% positive that when testing, you are always entering the `foreach` statement?)

To clarify the behavior of $GLOBALS:

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'bar';

var_dump($foo); // outputs 'bar'

if (true) {
    $GLOBALS['foo'] = 'bar2';
}

var_dump($foo); // outputs 'bar2'

function test() {
    var_dump($foo); // notice undefined variable - outputs NULL
    var_dump($GLOBALS['foo']); // outputs 'bar2'
    global $foo;
    var_dump($foo); // outputs 'bar2';
}

test();
```

Comment: You're right, I figured out the error and cannot believe how silly I was being. The reason it did not work is because the page that contains my PHP code is accessed by a javascript/AJAX function call. For some reason I forgot that the AJAX call doesn't have access to the rest of the PHP page. It only has access to the parameters it sends with the call. Thats why the global variable would keep displaying null when I would access it. $_POST['data'] wasn't sent with the AJAX call, so it was NULL from the start.